# Share chart and keep configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is it possible to share a dashboard chart and keep its configuration? 
Whenever I try it the resulting iFrame just shows the default configuration for that metric. Aggregations, type of chart, etc, are gone.

I could only find URL parameters to enable auto refresh (isAutoRefresh) and changing the timeframe.

Comment: Are you talking about Datastudio or something else?

Comment: I'm talking about log-generated metrics from which I've built charts for a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a chart of a custom dashboard by following these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/tips-and-tricks#chart_sharing).

If you have already followed the instructions provided and it is not working as expected, I would then suggest to file a PIT [here](https://issuetracker.google.com). You can file a PIT if you have encountered unexpected behavior with one of GCP's products or to request for a new feature to be implemented within GCP.